# Rails 5.2 credentials:edit doesn't like secret_key_base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been trying to debug my credentials file in my staging server. Whenever I try to edit the credentials on my staging server, I get the following error:

`` /var/www/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:583:in `validate_secret_key_base': `secret_key_base` for staging environment must be a type of String` ``

My `database.yml` file looks like the following:

```
---
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
development:
  <<: *default
  database: dev_db
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:development).fetch(:host) %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:development).fetch(:username) %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:development).fetch(:password) %>
  secret_key_base: <%= Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base.fetch(:development) %>
test:
  <<: *default
  database: test_db
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:development).fetch(:host) %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:development).fetch(:username) %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:development).fetch(:password) %>
  secret_key_base: <%= Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base.fetch(:development) %>
staging:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:staging).fetch(:name) %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:staging).fetch(:host) %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:staging).fetch(:username) %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:staging).fetch(:password) %>
  secret_key_base: <%= Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base.fetch(:staging) %>
production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:production).fetch(:name) %>
  host: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:production).fetch(:host) %>
  username: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:production).fetch(:username) %>
  password: <%= Rails.application.credentials.database.fetch(:production).fetch(:password) %>
  secret_key_base: <%= Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base.fetch(:production) %>
```

I think my staging's `secret_key_base` is of type `String`. I generated my `secret_key_base` using `rails secret`. Locally, when I bring up the rails console, I can view the `secret_key_base`s for my staging environment:

```
[1] pry(main)> Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base.fetch(:staging)
\=> "generated_using_rails_secret"
```

It returns a string but I still get the error message above whenever I try to access credentials in my staging environment.

Comment: what do you mean "edit the credentials"?

Comment: Rails 5.2 has a new feature called "credentials" that is eventually going to replace secrets.

Comment: I'm using Rails 5.2, which has deprecated "secrets" in favor of credentials. In fact, config/secrets.yml" doesn't even exist in a new rail 5.2 application.

https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2018/4/9/Rails-5-2-0-final/

Comment: so are you running `rails credentials:edit` to "edit" your credentials? I still see no reason to have any mention of this in the database.yml file https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up looking at the stack trace and digging into the `railties-5.2.0` gem.

Abbreviated stack trace:

```
ArgumentError: `secret_key_base` for staging environment must be a type of String`
/var/www/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:583:in `validate_secret_key_base'
/var/www/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:432:in `secret_key_base'
/var/www/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:176:in `key_generator'
/var/www/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:205:in `message_verifier'
```

I ended up looking in `railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:432:` and seeing the following bit of code:

```
# The secret_key_base is used as the input secret to the application's key generator, which in turn
# is used to create all MessageVerifiers/MessageEncryptors, including the ones that sign and encrypt cookies.
#
# In test and development, this is simply derived as a MD5 hash of the application's name.
#
# In all other environments, we look for it first in ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"],
# then credentials.secret_key_base, and finally secrets.secret_key_base. For most applications,
# the correct place to store it is in the encrypted credentials file.
def secret_key_base
  if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
    Digest::MD5.hexdigest self.class.name
  else
    validate_secret_key_base(
      ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] || credentials.secret_key_base || secrets.secret_key_base
    )
  end
end
```

I had mistakenly thought I could specify a `SECRET_KEY_BASE` for an individual environment. Instead, I could only specify one secret key base. The secret key base apparently has nothing to do with `database.yml`. I need to read up on it and what it actually does.

Comment: It's quite a mess, that the error message states, that there was no key found for thisandthat environment. There is no environment scope. Thank you for posting that code snippet. I updated my secrets file and took the secret_key_base out from under the production statement. Now it works. How many hours have been wasted on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you run `rails credentials:edit` from the command line it will decrypt the `config/credentials.yml.enc` file.

You can then edit this file to add environment based secret keys like you would have previously added to `config/secrets.yml`.

When you save this file it will be encrypted again with the new information included.

There is no reason to have the "secret_key_base" in your database.yml file as this will not have any impact.

[Nice Article on the new Rails credentials](https://medium.com/cedarcode/rails-5-2-credentials-9b3324851336)

Additionally just because rails now longer generates a `config/secrets.yml` file for you, as of rails 5.2, adding one will still work appropriately as it has in previous releases.

Comment: Actually, if your configuration is misconfigured, like mine is, `rails credentials:edit` will crash. Since my `secret_key_base` is a `Hash` instead of a `String`, attempting to edit the credentials just ends up crashing.

Comment: You are correct that there is no reason to have `secret_key_base` in my `database.yml` file.

Comment: @KurtMueller please post the full stack trace of running that command then